# ansetRequestProperty Content-Type and application/json

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I use a boundaryPostRequest like that

```
        final String delimiter = "--";
        con.setRequestMethod(fr.matelli.library.constante.HttpMethod.POST);
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);


        con.setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000);
        con.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
        con.connect();
        final OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write((delimiter + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
        os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n").getBytes());
        os.write(("\r\n" + value + "\r\n").getBytes());
        os.write((delimiter + boundary + delimiter + "\r\n").getBytes());


        os.close();
```

I want to add content/Type , json 
I tried :

```
        //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

and

```
os.write(("Content-Type: application/json").getBytes());
```

But it not work how can I setRequestProperty Content-Type and  application/json?

Comment: I see you have already set the content-type with this line:    
`con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);`

Comment: yes but i want add application/json too how can i do that

Comment: try adding it to that line as well

Comment: `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; application/json; charset=UTF-8; boundary=" + boundary);`

Comment: no when i use your suggest i have an WS error  and this error i got it in postman when i dont add on header  content-type : application/json

Comment: I think you should tell which error you get.

Comment: {"hasError":1,"message":"Champ nom obligatoire"}  but web service is in developement so this error tell the field ,name is necessary, i m getting the same error in postman when Content-Type json is missing

Comment: then it themes that server has a bug. Have you tried sending only a `application/json` as content type?

Comment: Yes i tested that and it give me error like this java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://151.8....../api/..../account

Comment: Did the server give you this error, or the android application crushed with this error?

Comment: Android application crached with this error

Comment: this way I'm sure you changed something else except removing everything from `Content-type` header

Comment: i just replace con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary); with this con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");